# Py2exe, Tkinter, and Setup File Problems?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, inno-setup, py2exe

I just finished creating a python program in 2.7 and I converted it to a `.exe` with `py2exe`.

Everything works fine when I run the converted executable file in the folder I placed it in with all of the images in it. After converting the python program to `.exe`, I proceeded to creating a `setup` file for it. I added all of the files associated with my project including `tkinter` in the `setup` file. I added pretty much everything that let me run the executable.

Once I finished creating the `setup` file, I opened it. I went through everything and finished installing it on my system and created a shortcut on my `Desktop`. When I tried to open it, it would not work. Instead of running the program, it tells me to open a log file in its folder in the Program Files. When I open the log file, I noticed an error. **How do I fix this?**

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "gui.py", line 10, in <module>
      File "Tkinter.pyc", line 1764, in __init__
    _tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
    {C:/Program Files (x86)/lib/tcl8.5} {C:/Program Files (x86)/lib/tcl8.5} C:/lib/tcl8.5         {C:/Program Files (x86)/library} C:/library C:/tcl8.5.15/library C:/tcl8.5.15/library
```

This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

Comment: I had the same problem. I had to ultimately switch to PyInstaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a bug on the virutalenv site which suggested the following https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/93

I imagine that you are encountering the same issue just without virtualenv 
the following set the correct paths which can then be included in the application please find the right path to TCL and TK for your python version

```
set "TCL_LIBRARY=C:\Python27\tcl\tcl8.5" 
set "TK_LIBRARY=C:\Python27\tcl\tk8.5"
```

> restart your cmd or shell

I believe that the TCL location have changed from there default ones.